# php color not showing properly

Tags: php, mysql, web, apache2, ubuntu-server

i am trying to FIX a crashed site designed by somebody else, designed using php and uses mysql database,(here is it's link http://www.wafms.co.cc on temporary server) now i want to port it to another server running ubuntu 8.04,when i shifted it's all lines in graph turned to BLACK!!no colour!! the graph rendered by php is not showing any colour except black, how is it possible?? what can be possible issue??

i am using the same files which i have used on http://www.wafms.co.cc and it's working fine but it's not working on this one!! :(

technical details:-

Existing server:-
running on 12.04,
mysql 5.2.42 and
apache2.4

Destination server:-
on which i am trying to port is running 
ubuntu 8.04 
mysql 5.1 and 
apache 2.1

can this (old ubuntu) be creating issue?? if so how to fix it?? because it cannot be updated as it is RTAI patched!!

so,please can u give some expert guidance and suggestion(s)?? :) regarding this UNIQUE issue!! ;)

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable to know if this is a possible solution or not.  Given my limited knowledge it seems like a possibility, but I wonder if some extra character was added to some file due to decoding error after you transfered the file.  something must have happened to the file where there is an error now.

Comment: could you post part of graph.php or at least see which package generates the graph?

Comment: are graphs generated by php GD library? please check in your destination server if gd extensions are properly installed and enabled using `phpinfo`. Also compare the version of gd in your temporary server and destination server

Comment: hi,@ajon no the files were properly copied i also had the same doubt so i compared them both source and destination using ssh and vim they all are same..
@mahdi yes i'll post it

Comment: @LoveSmltH-no graphs are generated directly through php colour render, and in addition i have checked that GD lib is installled properly!! :)

Comment: hello everyone, i found the solution..!! when i was debugging the issue, i noticed one strange thing that my php query were not working properly, this sparked an idea that my apache2 might now b functioning well!!
hence i UNISTALLED everything(Mysql,apache2,php5 everything) and installed sperate LAMPP package using xampp and run site through it,Voila... trick worked!! site started working properly even in OLD version!!

Comment: here is the code snippet
`//initialize image and colors..
 $im = @imagecreate($width-$cuty, $height) or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
 $background_color=ImageColorAllocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
 $text_color=imagecolorallocate($im,   0,  0,  0);
 $grid_color2=imagecolorallocate($im,230,230,230);
 $grid_color=imagecolorallocate($im, 180,180,180);
//get location details..
     $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','wafmessatcom');
 mysql_select_db('WAFMS',$con); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was Finally able to solve my issue!! the issue (maybe) was with my php5/apache2 installation! i tried running my site on a recent LAMPP server and out of my amusement, the site started running like a CHARM!!

it can be checked [www.wafms.co.cc](http://www.wafms.co.cc)

Dont know the technical reason but found the solution!!thank u for everybody's help..